# Using vim gf command with "@" webpack alias

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vim

I regularly use Vuejs and Webpack with the "@" character for file resolution, like so

```
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";
```

However, I cannot use the vim `gf` command to move to this file.

`E447: Can't find file "/components/MyComponent.vue" in path`

I have spent a couple of hours googling, messing around with the vim path and `includeexpr`. I have also tried a couple of plugins, like `vim-npr` or `vim-gotofile`.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution?

**edit**

Best thing I came up with so far is this:

`:set inex=substitute(v:fname,'^\\@\/','src/','')`

found it in [another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272493/resolving-javascript-modules-via-gf-in-vim-when-using-a-webpack-tilde-alias) where they where using the `~` character for this. However it doesn't work with `@`. I get this error when trying to `gf`

`E869: (NFA) Unknown operator '\@/'`

**My Solution**

With help from @romainl I now have this set up in both `after/ftplugin/vue.vim` and `after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`

```
setlocal isfname+=@-@
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^@\/','src/','')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a programming QA site so the code you came up with while "messing around with the vim path and `includeexpr`" is the most important part of your question. It is missing right now.

Comment: Fair enough! I updated my question with my best idea up to this point (which doesn't work)

Comment: I also had to add `set suffixesadd=.js,.vue,.scss,.json` so that it can recognize Vue files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the linked question, `~` is escaped because `~` has a special meaning for Vim's regexp engine: "matches the last given substitute string".

But `@` is not special in any way so there is no need to escape it:

```
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^@\/','src/','')
```

As you noticed, there is another problem. Vim uses `:help 'isfname'` to define `v:fname` but the option's value doesn't contain the `@` character by default so it is left out of `v:fname`. Since there is no `@` in `v:fname`, the pattern in `substitute()` doesn't match and we end up with:

| Actual string | `v:fname` | After `includeexpr` | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `@/foo/bar.vue` | `/foo/bar.vue` | `/foo/bar.vue` | Not found |

The solution is to add `@` to `isfname`:

```
setlocal isfname+=@-@
```

which gives us:

| Actual string | `v:fname` | After `includeexpr` | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `@/foo/bar.vue` | `@/foo/bar.vue` | `src/foo/bar.vue` | Found |

Tested to work with `$ vim -Nu NONE file.js`.

Now, the settings above being filetype-specific, it is best to put them in a ftplugin. Assuming the `filetype` of your buffers is `javascript`, a proper location would be:

```
" on Unix-like systems
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim

" on Windows
%USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\javascript.vim
```

YMMV.

---

Note that, in the answers to the linked questions, `^\\~` is incorrect and throws an error `E874`. The correct pattern is `^\~`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. It still doesn't find the file, though. 


What do you mean by 

`" in after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`?

Comment: That specific value for that specific option is filetype-specific so it should be in a ftplugin. If your `filetype` is `foo`, then the proper location is `after/ftplugin/foo.vim` in your `vimfiles` or `.vim` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 

path is `.,/usr/include,,,**`

Comment: I updated the post again with more code. Adding `@` to `v:fname` doesn't seem to work, I assume